# how to write regular expression to split strins in file based on " " in tcl?

Tags: regex, hashmap, tcl

I have 1 .txt file where data is stored in below format.

```
Name : Chetan Age :31 City : Mumbai
```

Here I want to split the data in below using regular expression using TCL

```
Name : Chetan 
Age :31 
City : Mumbai
```

and save this data in hashhmap

Comment: Format your question to better understand your input and output formats.

Comment: You need to be _very_ specific about what you're trying to do when using regular expressions. Which one is the input data? What happens with multi-word values on input (e.g., if the city were `New Delhi`)? Only by knowing exactly what you're really parsing can you write the correct regular expression. (Your sample data is simple enough, but the simplest solution would fail for even moderately more complex inputs. Hence we ask for more details.)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `Name`, `Age` and `City` are fixed strings? I guess city names and names can have values with spaces in them, right?

Comment: Consider Name, Age and City and key. and these are always fixed string
           
"Chetan" ,31 and "Mumbai" are values for keys

Answer (score 1):

You can may be use something like below to parse data.

```
> set data "Name: Chetan Age:31 City: Mumbai"
> regexp {Name(?:[\s:]+)(.*\S+)\s+Age(?:[\s:]+)(\d+)\s+City(?:[\s:]+)(.*\S+)} $data - name age city

> puts "Name:$name\nAge:$age\nCity:$city"

Name:Chethan
Age:31
City:Mumbai
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
Now I want to parse below string
"connect time: Mon May 23 02:15:60 2017 call duration: 00h00m40s"
Here  "connect time" and "call duration:" are key and "Mon May 23 02:15:60 2017" "00h00m40s"" are values respectively
here keys are always constant wheer as values changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
Now I want to parse below string
"connect time: Mon May 23 02:15:60 2017 call duration: 00h00m40s"
Here  "connect time" and "call duration:" are key and "Mon May 23 02:15:60 2017" "00h00m40s"" are values respectively
here keys are always constant wheer as values changes
There can be multiple blank space between "Mon May 23 02:15:60 2017" and  "call duration" (no fixed blank space)